# 'str' object is not callable in python

Tags: python, visual-studio, runtime-error

I'm calling this function `password()` in the `password()` function, hoping that it would start over. Then comes the 'str' object error.

code:

```
import time

def sleepFor(sleepForInt):
    time.sleep(sleepForInt / 1000)

def newScreen(): # adte it says
    for itemNew in range(26): 
        print("\n")

def logo(): #  ^~-
    newScreen()

    print("\t\t\t\tLeigh Studio")
    indent(6)

    return None

def indent(space): # adte it says
    for item in range(space):
        print("\n")

def password():
    userName = input("Enter registered UserName > ")
    user = userName

    indent(1)
    if userName == "leigh flix":
        confirm = input("Confirm UserName (y/n) > ")
        indent(2)

        if confirm == "y":
            password = input("\tenter password ) ")

            if password == "comics123":
                menu()

            else:
                print("Password is Incorrect")
                sleepFor(2000)
                password()
        else:
            password()
    else:
        print("No registered UserName as: " + user)
        sleepFor(2000)
        password()

def printID():
    print("C:/users/" + user)

def menu():
    response = input(printID())

    while response != "quit":

        if response == "time":
            time.ctime()

def main(): # main method
    logo()
    sleepFor(1200)
    newScreen()

    password()


# ___Runs program___
main()
```

error:
[image]

I don't know if there talking about the `userName = input("Enter registered userName")` or something else. oh, btw this is NOT a compile error but a runtime error, if happens when I don't type the right password (which is 'comics123').

The question I am asking Is there a different way of calling the `password()`
function where it doesn't get this error, and or a way to repeat asking for the user if the password is incorrect. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should not be checking for password correctness by raw string, by the way. That's unbelievably easy to hack.
You should look into using a salt with some sort of hashing algorithm like PBKDF2, and using it that way. Don't have a database? *At least* use a flat file storage somewhere and check against that, and make it read and right ONLY to the admin account calling the program..

Comment: @Vincenzzzochi The password is locally stored and protecting local resources that the user has full control over (from what I can gather). There's no hashing in the world that is going to increase security here.

Comment: @jd. If the intention is to place a password on which user can access the menu within this script only on a local computer, never to take in any other passwords from any other users from the outside world, then yes, you are correct. However, it is not far fetched to elaborate on a standard coding principle. If somehow s/he wishes to code anything involving multiple users that interact with the outside world. then this would be incorrect. And I do not wish to steer anyone in a direction that is less than perfect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is in this line:

```
password = input("\tenter password ) ")
```

After this line `password` in that scope is this string variable, not the function. Just rename this variable into something else to get around the problem.

Comment: thnx, didn't notice the overload >.>

Answer (score 1):

```
    if confirm == "y":
        password = input("\tenter password ) ")
```

You define a variable here named `password`, which shadows the `password()` function defined at the top level.

```
        if password == "comics123":
            menu()

        else:
            print("Password is Incorrect")
            sleepFor(2000)
            password()
```

Down here, you try calling the string that you got as input as if it were a method.

What you need to do is use different names for the string and the function. I recommend calling the function something like `request_password` or `input_password`.

Answer (score 1):

The `password()` calls fail because you have erroneously chosen to override the identifier `password` as being a local variable (by the `password = input("\tenter password ) ")` statement!) so hiding the global (function) name coinciding with it.  Use a **different** identifier for the local variable, e.g `passwd = input("\tenter password ) ")` (and then of course use `passwd` to refer to the string just entered!-) and you'll be fine.

Comment: And this is exactly the call hierarchy in python.. Local variables, in which case "password" is found and is not callable, and then global variables.
However, I believe he could get around this if he says `global password\nsleepFor(2000)\npassword()`

Comment: @Vincenzzzochi, not if he assigns to the identifier `password` -- try it!  As I said, he must use a **different** identifier instead (for the function and/or for the variable).